# Settimeout and Cleartimeout a Timer inside hashmap

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I tried to bind a timer to certain hashmap ID like this

```
function CreateTimer(id)
{
    var timer = setTimeout(function(id)
    {
        //Do something
    }, 3000,id)
    TimerMap.set(id,timer);
}
```

and I called a function to destroy the timer inside the hashmap after certain conditions :

```
function DestroyTimer(id)
{
    var timer = TimerMap.get(id);
    clearTimeout(timer);
    TimerMap.set(id, timer);
}
```

But somehow, the timer is still running. What did i miss here ?

NOTE : The timer is supposed to be destroyed if the id had expired, but in my case, the old timer is still running even if I already called the DestroyTimer function

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sipogacucu/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't get it, with the same function, mine is still running the old timer. it is causing my app to not behaving properly

Comment: We can't tell what you are doing wrong because you haven't provided a [MCVE].

Comment: Wait, what if in my code, i created 2 timers with the same Id.. will the destroyer function destroy both timers with the same id ?

Comment: No. When you write the details of the second one to the Map, you'll overwrite the details of the first one. Then you don't have the details you need to stop that timer.

Comment: That might be the cause..
I was thinking to store all the timers into an array, and to destroy it, i loop thru the array and clear each one of them.

Is it a bad approach ?

Comment: It's hard to tell. You haven't provided a [MCVE]

Comment: It's ok, Thank you man for the help..
Sorry i couldn't provide the complete necessary codes, because it is too complicated to break it down, since it's already added up to 5k lines.

But i think i know the problem now

Thanks